# How to dynamically choose a comparator to sort a collection of data by?

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have user input that's a list of 2 elements, and the order of the 2 elements might change. If the input is like ["byName", "byAge"], then I'd need to first sort a collection of data based off name, and if there's a tie between 2 elements, then sort by age.

So if input is

```
["byName", "byAge"]
```

and data is

```
[{"John", 81}, 
 {"Bob", 81}, 
 {"David", 47}]
```

sorted output would be

```
[{"Bob", 81}, 
 {"David", 47}, 
 {"John", 81}]
```

Likewise, if the input list is reversed like `["byAge", "byName"]`, then I'd sort the data by age, and use the name as a tiebreaker.

I'm unsure of what's the cleanest way to dynamically choose a comparator (I need comparators because there's other custom comparison logic I need to implement) based off the input? The most obvious way would be to directly perform a check on which element exists at index 0, i.e. in some lambda chain if `input.get(0) == "byAge"` then sort like this. But that's not really extensible, is it?

Comment: I got the sorted output mixed up but the site won't let me edit: Sorted output in the OP example should be [{"Bob", 81}, {"David", 47}, {"John", 81}]. Wanted to demonstrate what happens in a tiebreaker but that'd be applicable if the input was ["byAge", "byName"]

Comment: Why can't you edit? Just click the [edit] button beneath your post.

Comment: If you need to clarify anything - simply [edit] your question. Do not put it in comments.

Comment: I get the error message "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." when I attempt to edit ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Guess that's just me then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a map of comparators by name:

```
Map<String, Comparator<Person>> comparators = new HashMap<>();
comparators.put("byName", Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
comparators.put("byAge", Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
```

Then chain them on the fly:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("byName", "byAge");
Comparator<Person> comparator = input.stream()
        .map(comparators::get)
        .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
        .orElse((a, b) -> 0);
```

Comment: Ah of course. Not sure why I didn't think of this